# The import retrofit2.converter cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, retrofit2, moshi

I am unable to resolve error - **The import retrofit2.converter cannot be resolved**

I am using Eclipse Mars and added following JAR files as External JAR's

retrofit-2.1.0.jar
moshi-1.2.0.jar

it resolves "import retrofit2.Retrofit;" .. but unable to resolve "import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory;"

I am not using Maven .. but just adding JAR files .. any idea?

Thank you,

Jagdish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following dependency to pom.xml .. helped to resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```